# react-native fetch and basic authentication

Tags: react-native

I tried to use fetch with this syntax:

```
fetch("https://user:password@url", {
   ...
}).then((response) => {
   ...
}).done();
```

The same url works in CURL but returns 401 in React Native.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I found that this format `https://user:password@url` works well in CURL and node but not with fetch.

I had to use `base-64` npm module and pass through a Headers object.

```
// https://www.npmjs.com/package/base-64
const base64 = require('base-64');

...

var headers = new Headers();
headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + base64.encode("user:password"));

fetch("https://url", {
    headers: headers
  })
  .then((response) => { ... })
  .done();
`
```

Comment: Can please you share npm package name here ..!

Comment: For me, this is working only in debug mode. Did you guys any issue like this?

Comment: i am using rn-fetch-blob
 `RNFetchBlob.base64.encode(authString)`

Comment: @MaheshK, it is called `base-64`: https://npmjs.com/package/base-64

Answer (score 2):

You could have used `btoa()` instead of using the `base_64` module. `btoa()` is a function on the `Window`.

Comment: This is happening in React Native and btoa, at least then, was not available I think.

Answer (score 0):

Get request with authorization for React Native Mobile application, i have spent more time searching for these lines inside fetch

```
 var base64 = require("base-64"); // install it before use from npm i base-64

 const uname = "some username goes here";
 const pword = "some password goes here";

const getMovies = async () => {
   try {
     const response = await fetch(
       "API URL goes here",
       {
         headers: {
           Authorization: "Basic " + base64.encode(uname + ":" + pword),
         },
       }
     );

     data = await response.json();
     setData(data);

     console.log(data);
     // console.log(data.name);
     return data;
   } catch (error) {
     console.error(error);
   } finally {
     setLoading(false);
   }
 };

 useEffect(() => {
   getMovies();
 }, []);


// other code 

// inside return
  <FlatList
           keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
           data={data}
           renderItem={({ item }) => (
             <View style={styles.text_container}>
               <Text>{item.name}</Text>
               <Text>{item.images[0].name}</Text>
               <Text>{item.images[0].src}</Text>
             </View>
           )}
         />
```

Answer (score -1):

Without additional imports in React Native:

```
const Buffer = require("buffer").Buffer;

const credential = "Basic " + Buffer.from(email + ":" + password).toString("base64");

fetch(url, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: credential,
      }
    })
```

Comment: I get an error that package is missing