# fetch api: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I've tried to include everything I could find in the request, yet the error remains. How do I find out what's causing this? My AdBlocker extension has been deactivated.

```js
await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8080/hxo.json?dummy=2s21', 
{headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}, 
cache: "no-store", 
pragma: 'no-cache'})
.then(resp => resp.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(err => console.error('problem w fetch: ', err))
```

[image: screenshot of error in browser]

Comment: Hi, might be some another extension other than ad block? Like Privacy Badger or something

Comment: seems like an Authentication issue... did you use postman for view the json? is it working?

Comment: Getting this one now before the previous errors:
```
Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/hxxo.json?dummy=2s21' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Comment: if it is an authencation issue,, you need to pass the params with header. see here for [Basic authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34815853/react-native-fetch-and-basic-authentication/71122256#71122256).

Comment: Changing the URL to 127.0.0.1:8080 instead worked. Is there a workaround to this? (no authentication required, just fetching a json file)

Comment: clear the cache , try this [https://technowikis.com/5231/err-blocked-by-client-chrome-solution](https://technowikis.com/5231/err-blocked-by-client-chrome-solution).

Answer (score -2):

add `method` and remove `Pragma` property might solve the issue

```
fetch('url', 
  method: 'GET',
{headers: {'Content-Type': "application/json"}
})
```